# Using awk to obtain information only from the first instance

Tags: awk, text-processing

I am using awk to obtain data from a directory containing 300 output files.

Most of the relevant information I want to extract is in this format:

```
a bunch 
of text 
TOTAL ENERGY:   1234
a bunch 
of text 
not the same in
any way
DISPERSION COEFF:   5678
.
.
.
```

Except for dipole moment, which looks like:

```
Dipole Moment: [D]
     X:     1.2808      Y:     0.2908      Z:     1.0187     Total:     1.6622
```

Also, for whatever reason, dipole moment occurs TWICE in the file, in the same manner as mentioned above. The information is *exactly the same*.
I want to extract total dipole moment from this file.
I have a script running which can get this:

```
awk '/Dipole Moment: \[D\]/{found=1; next} found{print $NF; found=""; next} *.out
```

However, I get two lines of the same dipole moment.

**1. How do I avoid this?**

Secondly, I want to arrange all of this information in columns. I have a way of doing it for the nicely arranged properties, like TOTAL ENERGY and DISPERSION COEFF.
This is my script:

```
awk '/DISPERSION CORRECTION ENERGY/ {dee=$NF; next} /TOTAL ENERGY/{print $NF, dee;}' *.out
```

I get output that looks like

```
5678 1234
```

However, I have no way of arranging the dipole moment value in this table. How should I go about solving this?

For testing purposes:
file1.out:

```
a bunch 
of text 
TOTAL ENERGY:   1234
a bunch 
of text 
not the same in
any way
DISPERSION COEFF:   5678
.
.
Dipole Moment: [D]
     X:     1.2808      Y:     0.2908      Z:     1.0187     Total:     1.6622
.
.
.
Dipole Moment: [D]
     X:     1.2808      Y:     0.2908      Z:     1.0187     Total:     1.6622
```

file2.out:

```
a bunch 
of text 
TOTAL ENERGY:   4412
a bunch 
of text 
not the same in
any way
DISPERSION COEFF:   1111
.
.
Dipole Moment: [D]
     X:     1.28      Y:     0.08      Z:     1.87     Total:     1.22
.
.
.
Dipole Moment: [D]
     X:     1.28      Y:     0.08      Z:     1.87     Total:     1.22
```

Desired output:

```
1234 5678 1.6622
4412 1111 1.22
```

Comment: Where does "dee_in_file2 total_energy_in_file2" come from?

Comment: The first row is from the example input file I provided in the question, the terms ```dee_in_file2``` and ```total_energy_in_file2``` are just figures for data coming from file2.out @RamanSailopal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want (using GNU awk for `nextfile`):

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 { delete f; inDipole=0 }
    { f[$1" "$2] = $NF }
    inDipole { print f["TOTAL ENERGY:"], f["DISPERSION COEFF:"], $NF; nextfile }
    /Dipole Moment:/ { inDipole = 1 }
' file{1,2}
1234 5678 1.6622
4412 1111 1.22
```